# Vectorized Algorithm for finding the Shortest Path in a Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, parallel-computing

I know that you can calculate the shortest path in a vectorized fashion using Floyd-Warshall, e.g. like proposed by [Han and Kang](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/18-799B-CMU-spring05/material/sungchul-sukchan.pdf), however I want the matrix, they call "via", the actual route taken through the graph.

Is it possible to retrieve this "via" matrix from a similar vectorized algorithm?

Actually I do not need all-pairs shortest path, but have two nodes, that I just wish to calculate the distance between, however I want to do it vectorized. I cannot seem to find algorithms, that allow me to get the actual path, and not just the distance, when doing it vectorized.

Is it at all possible?

Comment: Can't you use the normal way to also compute paths during floyd warshall? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction

Comment: What exact restrictions do you tie to the term "vectorized"? One can, for instance, parallelize Bellman-Ford on shared-memory architectures but I'm not sure the algorithm I have in mind counts as "vectorized".

Comment: @Raphael With vectorized I mean "can be done with vector algebra", so that it indeed can be parallelized. Implementation-wise I want to do it with "pure" NumPy. Essentially I want to substitute the  nested for-loops with matrix multiplication.

Comment: @adrianN The "normal way" of Floyd-Warshall isn't vectorized, but three nested for-loops, so while it solves my problem of getting the "via"-matrix, it doesn't scale. With the vectorized way that Han and Kang suggests I do not get the "via"-matrix, but the computation for the shortest path is vectorized. I want a mix between the two.

Comment: If I read the paper correctly, they eventually call FWI, that contains the same if statement as the normal algorithm. I think you could add the path computation there, like in the normal algorithm. BTW, have you seen [this](https://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ss12/AdvancedGraphAlgorithms/Slides14.pdf)? I think you should update your question with *why* you need this. If it's for speedup only, I think you'll have a hard time beating Dijkstra.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. To me it again seems like they only calculate the actual distance, using matrix multiplication, which is really nice, but they do not compute the via-matrix. The problem that Han and Kang don't state, is that with vector programming, you factor out all the for-loops, so you don't have actual recursive calls, you just have matrix multiplication, which makes everything nice and fast, but doesn't give you the via-matrix, only the distance.

Comment: Dijkstra's is fast i theory, but in practice I might do better with computing 10.000 steps at a time on the GPU, instead of doing O(nlogn) sequentially. As always it really depends on your problem size.